# Babel plugin doesn't run as expected - output is not always shown

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I have made a babel plugin that should find all functions with a specific name in order to get the input parameters. However, it doesn't run as I expect it to.

Right now I simply `console.log` the expected parameter, but they are not always found.

```js
module.exports = function ({ types: t }) {
    return {
        visitor: {
             CallExpression: function(path) {
                 const node = path.node;
                 console.log("name:", node.callee.name);
                 if(node.callee.name === 'i18n') {
                     const argumentNode = node.arguments[0];
                     if(t.isStringLiteral(argumentNode)){
                         console.log(argumentNode.value);
                     }

                 }
             }
        }
    };
};
```

In fact, the first `console.log`:

```js
console.log("name:", node.callee.name);
```

creates like 20 outputs, but I'm expecting way more.

In `.babelrc`, I have added my `ast-crawler` like this:

```js
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports",
    "ast-crawler"
  ],

  "presets": [
    ["es2015"],
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

I have tried to change the order, but the result is the same.

Sometimes I get all the expected output, but why don't I always get it? Does babel only cache some of my code, so if I wait for x minutes I will get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that babel cache was used.

```js
query: {
          cacheDirectory: '.babelcache'
        }
```

After removing the cache I got the expected output